# UICollectionVIew not displaying cells adequately on ios7 although works fine on is6

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios7, uicollectionview

I have a simple implementation of a `UICollectionView` with default layout that works fine on **iOS6**. 
When transitioning the code on **iOS7**, the default `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` seems not to work: all the cells are located on the top left corner at the exact same locations (one on top of the others).

Note that I do not update cell.frame.origin, nor cell.center in:

```
(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {}
```

Am I wrong?
What should I do it?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You need to post more code showing how `UICollectionView` is being populated and displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood my problem:

I had the follwoing line in my code:

```
   [cell.layer setPosition: CGPointMake(-5, -5)];
```

which explains why the cell was located at the top left corner.

But strangely, when running on ios6, this line had no effect (and that's why I even forgotten it was there) whereas it does have on ios7.

I simply delete the line, and now everything is running fine on both ios6 and ios7.